# Wireless broken after latest 12.04 update

Tags: wireless

I updated 12.04 yesterday and it broke my wireless connection.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

l@ubuntu:~$ lspci|grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

In the hardware drivers, I see - rt3090sta is activated but currently not in use. WICD does not show wireless networks.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

please, try:

`sudo modprobe rt3090sta`

Comment: Its perhaps very useful if you explain in your answer why the OP should do this, what they should expect to happen, how to revert etc.